# Conditionally replacing the last characters of a string

Tags: java

I have a string, say `xyzabc_1_1`.

I want to first test if the **last** characters are `_1` and if so, replace the last `_1` with `_01_1`. The string will become `xyzabc_1_01_1`.

For finding if the last digits are `_1` I'm using

```
str1.matches("^.*_\\d$")
```

But don't know the second part, i.e. how to replace the last occurrence with `_01_1`.

Answer (score 4):

To replace the string, you can just grab a substring and concatenate your new suffix. Additionally, you can use [`endsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) instead of the regular expression. IMHO it's more readable.

```
public String replaceSuffix (String target) {
    if (!target.endsWith("_1")) {
       return target;
    }

    return target.substring(0, target.length() - 2) + "_01_1";
}
```

And just for the fun of it, here's a more reusable version for replacing different things:

```
public String replaceSuffix (String target, String suffix, String replacement) {
    if (!target.endsWith(suffix)) {
        return target;
    }

    String prefix = target.substring(0, target.length() - suffix.length());
    return prefix + replacement;
}
```

Invoked as (for your specific example):

```
String replaced = replaceSuffix("xyzabc_1_1", "_1", "_01_1");
```

Depending on your expected input, you might also want some null/empty/length checks on `str`.

Comment: thanks....but what if the string we want to replace is not only '_1' but can be any integer like _2 or _3

Comment: That's somewhat of a different question. You can probably build a solution for that based on this. There are plenty of different ways. Maybe loop over a collection and replace each. Or maybe use a regular expression if that works best. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple one-liner, using `replaceAll()` and back-references:

```
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("_\\d$", "_01$0");
```

It's not clear if the `01` is based on the `1` or is a constant. ie if `2` were to become `02_2` then do this instead: `str1.replaceAll("_(\\d)$", "_0$1_$1")`

Here's a test:

```
String str1 = "xyzabc_1_1";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("_\\d$", "_01$0");
System.out.println(str2);
```

Output:

```
xyzabc_1_01_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather replace the whole string with the new one. Create a new string with the '_01_1' concatenated. Then replace.

Answer (score 0):

Done but needs optimization...

```
String str1 = "xyzabc_1";

    /* System.out.println(str1.matches("^.*_\\d$")); */

    try {
        if (str1.matches("^.*_\\d$")) {
            String cutted = str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf("_"),
                    str1.length());
            str1 = str1.replaceAll(cutted, "_01" + cutted); //
            System.out.println(str1);
        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```